# Como extrair determinado texto do pdf com node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tenho um código que transforma um pdf em um csv porem eu querotransforma em csv uma determinada parte do pdf e não o pdf inteiro.
código abaixo:

```
   const fs = require('fs'),
    PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
    
    const analisarPdf = new PDFParser(this, 1);
    
    analisarPdf.on("pdfParser_dataError", 
    errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
    
    analisarPdf.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
      fs.writeFile("./Arquivos.csv", analisarPdf.getRawTextContent(), ()=>{console.log("Pdf convertido!");});
    });
    
    analisarPdf.loadPDF("teste.pdf", teste);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes selecionar o texto entre duas palavras ou o texto entre duas linhas.

```
analisarPdf.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
    texto = analisarPdf.getRawTextContent();
    var inicio = "início";
    var fim = "fim";
    texto1 = texto.substring(
        texto.indexOf(inicio), 
        texto.lastIndexOf(fim) + fim.length
    );
    texto2 = texto.split('\n').slice(5, 10).join("");
    fs.writeFile("./Arquivos.csv", texto1, ()=>{console.log("Pdf convertido!");});
});
```